# Select object rendered using min3d on android

Tags: android, opengl-es

While going through the sample code given by min3d library, I cam across an example for loading multiple objects from a .obj file.
It loads the car's body and 4 tires as different objects.
Is it possible to add a touch event to can detect which one of the 5 objects were touched/selected. If not , is there any other library which can load .obj file and enable me to detect the selected object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

min3D is obsolete now, the new framework is called [Rajawali](http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2011/08/23/announcing-rajawali-an-opengl-es-2-0-based-3d-framework-for-android/). It supports object picking, see the tutorial [here](http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2012/03/23/rajawali-tutorial-12-object-picking/).

Comment: the tutorials and screenshots look great...downloading and trying them right away....

Comment: I tired the examples of Rajawali. It seems like the colour picking has been used for selecting objects which would fail in my case as the whole object is of the same colour.